# how do I get the bot to send a message at startup?

Tags: telegram

how do I get the bot to send a message at startup?

it didn't work out in BotFather, you can only create a bot and its profile there.
in Manubot, advertising after the actions performed, even some services complement messages that are not even added.

Answer (score 0):

You have to code the bot using a programming language. It is the standard way. For example, using python, you can:

Install Python

Install a library:

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

`bot.py`:

```py
import telebot

BOT_TOKEN = `YOU_BOT_TOKEN_HERE`

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

# send message at startup
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
```

Run it:

```
python bot.py
```

This will work.

And to make it 24/7 available, you have to make it hosted on a cloud hosting provider like Heroku, Google Cloud or something.